# SQL Newbie: How to compare all rows within a column to reflect how many rows are "cheaper/less than" the respective row?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case

**Where I am having trouble**
I believe that I will need to use COUNT; however, I am lost as to how I would compare a row to each row within the same column and then count how many rows are less/cheaper than the respective row. Thank you in advance!
**Here is the official problem I am attempting to solve:**
*"Using the sample schema, write a SQL statement that will return all products in the Products table and a count of how many other products are cheaper than the product's price."*

[Image example of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe5wo.png)

[Image of all tables relative to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbUt6.png)

**My code so far...**

```
SELECT 
product_id, 
product_name, 
product_price, 
CASE WHEN product_price >????
END AS products_cheaper_count  
FROM [Products]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need to use `COUNT` in inner `SELECT` query to get count of all the products cheaper than the current one, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_price,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE product_price < p.product_price) AS products_cheaper_count
FROM products;
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you use the following code

```
declare @price float(24) = 7.50
select count(*)
    from Products sq
    where sq.product_price < @price
```

The resulting count would be 2, which we know is true from the example you showed us. However, this is done with a fixed value for *@price*, and we want it to change for each record in the table. So we simply extend this idea and use a correlated subquery

```
select product_id, product_name, product_price,
        ( select count(*)
            from Products sq
            where sq.product_price < pro.product_price
        ) as products_cheaper_count
    from Products pro
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name, p.product_price,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products pc WHERE pc.product_price < p.product_price) AS products_cheaper_count
    FROM products p
```

Comment: Try this last sql !